# Suggested document-oriented database (MongoDB) design

Tags: database-design, mongodb, database-schema

I'm researching alternative database solutions for an existing e-commerce site, and thought I should give NoSQL a glance.

Our current design is a very traditional relational design. However, the site functionality and structure lends itself more to a CMS. The types of pages can be broken down as such:

- Category Listing (list products from a particular category or custom query)
- Home Page
- Sub-Category Home Page
- Custom content Page (press releases, promotional, etc...)
- Product

Each of these has many things in common, and could benefit from a document-oriented design.

ACID is not critical. Key transactional data (read: stock) is maintained elsewhere. Overselling is caught when orders are processed off-site. Stock is updated on the site from the off-site location at regular intervals.

Rough Collection Design:

```
{
  {
    "title":"Some page Title",
    "type":"Page",
    "key":"some-page-title",
    "body":"Lorem Impsum..."
  },
  {
    "title":"Some product",
    "type":"Product",
    "key":"widgets\/some-product",
    "data":{
      "stock":3,
      "price":25.13,
      "category":"Widgets",
      "images":["image1.jpg","image2.jpg"]
    }
  }
}
```

The other data (Customers, Orders, etc...) would be located in appropriately designed collections. The "Pages" are the most accessed items, and I would like to keep them centralized. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by you want to keep "Pages" centralized?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, hadn't noticed that there was a question. I should rephrase what I mean by Pages. I'm thinking of classifying everything on the site as a page. Each page has it's own data, which determines what is displayed on that page. There are common elements between them (such as title) but other elements might be different. So, I'd like to keep all these elements contained within their own collection

Comment: If no of pages are not big, then consider keeping separate key for each page, this way you will get away with overhead of drilling down in the "pages" array.